# Pygame: Sorting sprites in group based upon position on screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently creating a space invaders game using Pygame.

I create the Alien enemies and add them to a group called "aliens".

I have multiple rows of invaders, created using the following code:

```
yPos = self.top_boundary
    for r in range(self.total_rows):
        xPos = self.left_boundary
        for i in range(self.invaders_per_row):
            self.alien = Invader(xPos, yPos)
            self.aliens.add(self.alien)
            xPos += 32
        yPos += 40
```

Now, in order to reverse the direction of the invaders when they're on screen, I need to determine which invader is the "left most" invader and check if it has reached the left hand side of the screen.

My problem is, they're not stored in the group in any particular order. How can I determine which invader has the left most position?

An alternative method I could use would be to use lists to store the objects instead. Then I could easily iterate through the lists to determine which invader is the left most. Would this be a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`OrderedUpdates`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates) class which *maintains the order in which the Sprites were added to the Group for rendering*.

Comment: Just `for sprite in self.aliens`, being `self.aliens` your `OrderedUpdates` instance!

Comment: I would +1, but can't due to low reputation, sorry! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a collection of `Invader` objects which have an attribute for their x-Position, you can just use `min` to find the one with the smallest x-Position. Minimal example:

```
class Invader(object):
    def __init__(self, xpos, ypos):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.xpos, self.ypos))

invaders = [Invader(3, 2), Invader(4, 9), Invader(0, 100)]
print(min(invaders, key=lambda x: x.xpos)) # prints '(0, 100)'
```

Having a collection of all your invaders seems natural to me for a game like this.